# Applying for a US visa without travel experience

Tags: usa

Can I apply for a USA B1/B2 visa without having any traveling experience? What are my chances of getting the visa?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can Ghana man. My first international trip and visa was to the USA.

Nobody can give you your chances of getting the visa although without travel experience typically your chances are lower than people with travel experience.

Comment: Perhaps you should add "...and I am also Ghanaian"?