# Saudi Arabia resident seeking a US visa

Tags: usa, tourist-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am living and working in Saudi Arabia for last 16 years( I am having a good paying job and I am living here with my kids & wife )

How can I get US visit visa? I don't have travel history, & I didn't visit my home  country for last seven years

1. To prove strong ties I have a well paid job in Saudi Arabia
2. To prove strong ties I have a property under my name in Pakistan
3. I have enough funds to stay for 30 or more days in the US.

I have confusion that I don't have a travel history, there are visa stamps of Saudia Arabia to Pakistan only & I have a history of living in Doha, Qatar with my father while my father was working in Qatar Armed forces during my childhood. 
Please need your kind good advise.

Comment: If you've been able to remain outside Pakistan for 7 years, then by definition you have no strong ties _there_, property or no property.

Comment: So about strong ties what is your advice /opnion about point 1. To prove strong ties I have a well paid job in Saudi Arabia

Comment: One more strong tie is that I have kids and family which are not going with me to USA + I have job in a good company   in Saudi Arabia so definately I have  to come back doesnt that enough to proof my ties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps shortening your intended stay in the US might help, also consider visiting another country(ies) before applying to the US. Your ties to Saudi Arabia include your family, since it’s not your intention for them to travel with you. I’d thoroughly research and understand the requirements before applying to ensure my application addressed all the elements, this information may be of interest if you’ve not already read it. https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-denials.html

Answer (score 5):

The only advice we can give is for you to present as strong an application as possible and hope for the best.  Your question implies that you understand the important factors.

Your stable employment certainly works in your favor, though you should be aware that "well paid" is relative to the cost of living, so if you haven't already taken that into account, you should do so and reassess whether your savings and salary are adequate for your plans.

Your nationality, place of residence, and apparently Muslim name can work against you in the current climate, but they shouldn't by themselves result in a rejection; other Pakistani citizens have certainly been able to visit the United States.

Your lack of travel history may attract greater scrutiny to your application, but others have also had successful applications for US visas in that situation, including at least one [user on this site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/114241/19400).